# CAGradientLayer slow?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, core-animation

I have a series of CAGradientLayers which are made when a view is loaded, but scrolling through them causes a bit of lag. Is there a way to reduce this lag?

Comment: Quite vague.  You are likely going to have to add a bit more detail to get helpful response.  I haven't had performance problems using built-in gradients.

Answer (score 12):

Make sure to add:

```
l.shouldRasterize=YES;
l.rasterizationScale=[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

Comment: I love you for this, @Gilad.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do and how you're coding it this is going to be very difficult, if not impossible, to answer. Assuming everything is being done correctly, rasterizing the layers may help matters (`layer.shouldRasterize = YES`). But there may be improvements to me made in the code before having to resort to that.